# Modern CMake Library containing sub-libraries

Tags: cmake

I have several libraries (subproject) as part of one main library. How can I aggregate the sub-libraries (b) in a "main-library" (a)?

The Goal would be to only have a library `a` and use the sublibraries as follows `#include <b/b.h>`

(is there a way to have the include paths as follows: `#include <a/b/b.h>` ?)

assuming the following folder structure:

```
a
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- aConfig.cmake
`-- b
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- include
    |   `-- b
    |       `-- b.h
    `-- src
        `-- b.cpp
```

I have the following library `a` depending on library `b`. library `a` must be installed and thus found with the `find_package(a CONFIG REQUIRED)` command in a modern CMake way. The library does not provide any implementation but should aggregate the sublibraries. I thought that making the `target_include_directories` `Public` would propagate the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property to the library `a` since it links against `b` but I could not manage to get it to work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

project(a)

find_package(Eigen3 3.2.2 REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(b)

## Build
add_library(a)
add_library(a::a ALIAS a)

target_link_library(a
PUBLIC
  b::b
)

## Install

include(GNUInstallDirs)

# create export set
install(TARGETS a
  EXPORT "aTargets"
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
)

install(
  DIRECTORY
    b/include/
  DESTINATION
    "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}"
)

install(EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}Targets"
  FILE
    "aTargets.cmake"
  NAMESPACE
    "a::"
  DESTINATION
    lib/cmake/a
)

install(
  FILES
    "aConfig.cmake"
  DESTINATION
    "lib/cmake/a"
)
```

Comment: When you `find_package(a)`, which I assume you are using instead of a "super build," would you like to keep using `#include <b/b.h>` in consumers of `a`, or would you like to have `#include <a/b/b.h>` instead? I could not get what you meant within the parentheses.

Comment: `#include <b/b.h>` would be consistent to the subproject's include path and allow consistent use if only a part of the message would be included. The main idea is to only link one library `a` and use all the subproject's libraries.

Comment: I have posted an answer. I hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [interface libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) together with [relocatable packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_include_directories.html#creating-relocatable-packages) seem to solve your problem. Below is a minimal working example.

Assume that we have the following directory structure

```
.
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   └── b
│   │   │       └── b.h
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── b.cpp
│   ├── c
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   └── c
│   │   │       └── c.h
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── c.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp

9 directories, 9 files
```

where `a` is your super project that contains other subprojects. The contents for the `b` and `c` libraries are as follows:

```
# a/b/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(b CXX)

add_library(b
  include/b/b.h
  src/b.cpp
)
add_library(b::b ALIAS b)

target_include_directories(b
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

install(TARGETS
  b
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
)
install(DIRECTORY include/b DESTINATION include)

/* a/b/include/b/b.h */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double funcb(const double);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

/* a/b/src/b.cpp */
#include "b/b.h"

extern "C" {
double funcb(const double x) { return x + x; }
}

# a/c/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(c CXX)

add_library(c
  include/c/c.h
  src/c.cpp
)
add_library(c::c ALIAS c)

target_include_directories(c
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

install(TARGETS
  c
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
)
install(DIRECTORY include/c DESTINATION include)

/* a/c/include/c/c.h */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double funcc(const double);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

/* a/c/src/c.cpp */
#include "c/c.h"

extern "C" {
double funcc(const double x) { return x * x; }
}
```

Then, you simply make `a` an `INTERFACE` library as follows:

```
# a/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(a)

add_subdirectory(b)
add_subdirectory(c)

add_library(a INTERFACE)
add_library(a::a ALIAS a)
target_link_libraries(a
  INTERFACE
    b::b
    c::c
)
```

Finally, your application will be using the `b` and `c` libraries as usual:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "b/b.h"
#include "c/c.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  cout << funcb(5) << '\n';
  cout << funcc(5) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

and the corresponding `CMakeLists.txt` will read

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(app)

add_subdirectory(a)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE a::a)
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I will get back once I got it working. Need to work on some other things and my ugly workaround allow the same usage. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

It will require you to change the directory structure. Header inclusion are tied to physical paths, and there are no physical path that resemble `a/b/b.h`. The solution will be to change the directory structure with something like this:

```
a
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- aConfig.cmake
`-- b
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- include
    |   `-- a
    |       `-- b
    |           `-- b.h
    `-- src
        `-- b.cpp
```

And set the target include directory to `a/b/include`

Comment: That's what I already thought of but didn't want that compromise since the  b subcomponent would need knowledge of a. I just added the sublibrary sources and headers to the library `a` and installed the headers in `include/grid_map/` alongside the other includes. This is quite dirty and ugly but since the library is a fork of a ROS Package I want to diverge the folder structure as little as possible. If there is a way to aggregate libraries that would be nice though. I could live with the original include paths.